# How to move the fa-fa icon to right and space between

Tags: html, css

Can anyone please let me know. How to move the fa-fa.trash icon to right most corner of the drop down option

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<li class="" style="false">
  <label class="">
    <input type="radio" data-name="selectItem" value="testvale" original-value="testvale">&nbsp;<span>testvale</span>
    <div>
      <a class="delete-savedFilter" type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
    </div>
  </label>
</li>
```

[image: 1]

That trash icon should move to right corner
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: add your sample snippet

Comment: A lot of unnecessary tags, you need to present the issue as it is, there's clearly more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily by using `flex` on `justify content` space between css property.

Also, have added a class to your `li` to do css on that instead of doing on a `label` => as it might mess up the css of all the labels on the page.

You can read more about `flex` [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Run snippet below.

```css
.filter-trash-icon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<li class="filter-trash-icon"><label class=""><input type="radio" data-name="selectItem" value="nfwsfd" original-value="nfwsfd">&nbsp;<span>nfwsfd</span><div> <a class="delete-savedFilter" type="button"></a></div></label><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></li>
```

Comment: This filter-trash-icon class has  (css) file    .filter-trash-icon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

Comment: Please check the code i have done, for me its not working   <li class="filter-trash-icon"><label class=""><input type="radio" data-name="selectItem" value="nfwsfd" original-value="nfwsfd">&nbsp;<span>nfwsfd</span><div> <a class="delete-savedFilter" type="button"></a></div></label><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></li>

Comment: @ragavigr I have updated my answer check now. Its working fine with `.filter-trash-icon`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of flexbox:

```css
label {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <li class="" style="false"><label class="">
    <span>
    <input type="radio" data-name="selectItem"
           value="testvale" original-value="testvale">&nbsp;
      <span>testvale</span></span>
    <div> <a class="delete-savedFilter" type="button"><span>trash</span></a> </div></label></li>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its not ideal to so CSS on `label` as there might be other `label` on the same page which could cause an issue with this. Considering using `class` or `id` to the element

Comment: You are right, this snippet was just an example to show, obviously by assigning some class/id will be better.

Answer (score 0):

Remove outer div of link button trash and apply this css

```
style="float:right;"
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<li class="" style="false">
  <label class="">
    <input type="radio" data-name="selectItem" value="testvale" original-value="testvale">&nbsp;<span>testvale</span>
     
      <a class="delete-savedFilter" style="float:right;" type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
    
  </label>
</li>
```